# how to install a toolbox in a mac?

Tags: macos, matlab, toolbox

how to install a toolbox, such as 'econometrics', in a mac?

I have put the file under the toolbox file, and also set path, update path.  But just does not work.

I need to a function 'price2ret'..

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a Mac so I never try to install toolbox but maybe have a look to this blog :

[Matlab ToolBox on Mac](http://blogs.cuit.columbia.edu/bl2490/2012/10/08/matlab-toolbox-installation/)